# Is it correct to use plus or minus symbol before standard deviation?

Tags: standard-deviation, mean, standard-error

I have represented standard deviation as "±SD" before in publications. But I like to have opinions on this. Is it appropriate to use the notation '±' with SD ? Or is it only for Standard error ?

Comment: The the second bullet point of the [wiki page for the plus minus operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plus-minus_sign) already answers your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes! you can represent standard deviation as "±SD".

For Example:- $\bar x\pm 2\times SD$, it just shows the lower and upper limit for most of individual output $x_i$ of Normal data. ($\mu ~rather~than~ \bar x$)

and, $\bar x\pm 2\times SE~of~mean$, shows lower and upper limit of population mean.

Comment: $\bar{x} \pm 2\mathrm{SD}$ could be an asymptotic 95% prediction interval for a Gaussian random variable (asymptotic because the sample mean, & perhaps the standard deviation, are estimated from the data; so exact prediction intervals are somewhat wider).

Comment: Yes @Scortchi! That's why I said most of individual output.

Comment: why times 2? this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/38557/40817) says it's  $\bar{x} \pm \mathrm{SD}$